# How to await iOS openURL overridden method?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a share feature in which a mail application can open my application by clicking the share button. I am able to open my app when user click share from mail app, the issue is with OpenUrl method.

Below is my OpenUrl method:

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
{
    Upload(url);
    return true;
}

async public Task<bool> Upload(NSUrl SharedUri)
{
  //upload 
}
```

Problem with the above code is since the `Upload` function is not awaited, before the upload function finishes the app is opened.

How can I await the task in `OpenUrl`?

Comment: why you want to wait once the `OpenUrl` method is triggered rather you can  show some indicator while uploading file

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have many options here, one of which is returning Upload's result. Remember to await time consuming task inside of Upload.

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
{
        return this.Upload(url).Result;
}

async public Task<bool> Upload(NSUrl SharedUri)
{
      await SomeUploadTask();
      return true;
}
```

I agree with Sunil that you should show some indication of an action to user, here's the control you should use: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator/

Comment: Thanks for the response, the suggestion doesn't work for me. The app gets stuck at the splash-screen and then crashes. Could you suggest any other way?

Comment: I also noticed that the appdelegate has a commnet `// You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.` That could be the reason?

Comment: can you tell me what exactly is the workflow here? In mail app you open your app using share functionality on file/mail? And then in your app what are you doing with this content and what should happen next - you should close the app and return to mail app after this upload task is finished or you'll stay in your app?

Comment: Yes I open my app from mail app using share function. Then once I get the file being shared I want to save that file locally in my app folder and add a new entry to the local xml file of the app. Once the entry is made the app should open with the list of entries from XML file(Which should include new entry)

Comment: In my code everything is working except the list does not refresh with the new entry as I do not have await function. When I open some other page and goes back to list page the entry is displayed.

Comment: The thing you can do is to store entries in ObservableCollection<Entry>, bind the ui list to it and then add new item after the task is finished, like this:

Upload(url).ContinueWith((x) => observableList.Add(entry))

The ui is going to update itself when you'll add new collection item.

Comment: I have a cross-platform app and I bind the list in xamarin.forms peoject